# \pagestyle{fancy} doesn't work after applying \pagestyle{plain}

Tags: fancyhdr

Consider the following example, if the `plain` page style has been modified with `\fancypagestyle`, then `\pagestyle{fancy}` doesn't work if one has applied `\pagestyle{plain}` before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain} % with this, '\pagestyle{fancy}' below doesn't work
\section{Test}

\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy} % doesn't work
\subsection{test}

\end{document}
```

Page two should be like

[image]

But now it is

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fancy page style takes by default its settings from the environment. So it can change if you change some header. As mentioned in the documentation you can use the style `fancydefault` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
  \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain} % 
\section{Test}

\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancydefault} % 
\subsection{test}

\end{document}
```

The alternativ is to define fancy with `\fancypagestyle` too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain} % 
\section{Test}

\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy} % 
\subsection{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been making this mistake since the first day I encountered with `fancyhdr`, and it is not until now that I realize that it may cause trouble.

Comment: Perhaps `\pagestyle{fancy}` should be placed after `\fancypagestyle{fancy}`? `\fancyhf{}` doesn't seem to get executed if `\pagestyle{fancy}` is in front of `\fancypagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: yes, you are right, edited.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is how `\pagestyle` works. `\pagestyle{plain}` executes all the commands given in its defintion (in addition to the fancyhdr setup), so `\fancyhf{}` is executed in the global context.

A later `\pagestyle{fancy}` doesn't undo this. Only when the `\pagestyle{plain}` is given in a local context, its changes are restricted to that context. This happens for example with `\thispagestyle`, or when you give `\pagestyle{}` in a group (see solution 1). Otherwise you must put the header definitions explicitely in pagestyle `fancy` (see solution 2).

In the next version of `fancyhdr` I will have a better solution for this, but for now you can use one of the solutions below.

**Solution 1:** Use a group. **Note** the \clearpage must be inside the group, otherwise the original headers will leak into the previous page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\pagestyle{plain} % with this, '\pagestyle{fancy}' below doesn't work
\section{Test}

\clearpage
\endgroup
\pagestyle{fancy} % doesn't work
\subsection{test}

\end{document}
```

**Solution 2:** Put the header definitons inside the pagestyle `fancy`. **Note** This will only work in fancyhdr version 4, otherwise you will have to use a different pagestyle name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{
  \fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
  \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain} % with this, '\pagestyle{fancy}' below doesn't work
\section{Test}

\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy} % doesn't work
\subsection{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You mentioned "In the next version", will "Solution 2" still be available by then?

Comment: Solutions 1 and 2 are available now if your `fancyhdr.sty` is up to date.

Comment: I mean, solution 2 will not break with the future version, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the future version will use a new command. So existing code will remain working.